# Watchdog Observer not handling all files

Tags: python, pandas, function, python-watchdog

I have a segment of code that calls a plethora of functions into action using watchdog observers to detect a change.  The issue is that with the snippet of code below ONLY the Sales.tsv file will trigger the process, if I run the Service.tsv file it just locks up and then it won't even process the Sales.tsv one after that it also doesn't return the "Something went wrong" message.  The Sales.tsv file will also trigger the print('Document Found, processing...'), the Service.tsv one will not.

I have also tried changing between if, elif, and else none of them work either.  Have also tried changing the positioning and placing sales above the service.tsv segment with no luck.

both files have the correct file extension, the correct name, only difference being what is contained in each and the size of the files.  the sales file is only 8kb, the service one is 23kb.

```
folder_to_track = '/Users/myname/Desktop/New Reports'
folder_destination = '/Users/myname/Desktop/Old Reports'


class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
            for filename in os.listdir(folder_to_track):
                file_exists = os.path.isfile(folder_destination + '/' + filename)
                while file_exists:
                    file_exists = os.path.isfile(folder_destination + '/' + filename)

                if os.path.splitext(filename)[-1] == '.tsv':
                    print('Document Found, processing...')

                    if filename == 'Service.tsv':
                        src = folder_to_track + '/' + filename
                        new_destination = folder_destination + '/' + filename
                        servicedf = pd.read_csv(src, sep='\t')
                        os.rename(src, new_destination)
                        service_report(servicedf)

                    if filename == 'Sales.tsv':
                        src = folder_to_track + '/' + filename
                        new_destination = folder_destination + '/' + filename
                        salesdf = pd.read_csv(src, sep='\t')
                        os.rename(src, new_destination)
                        sales_report(salesdf)

                else:
                    print('Something Went Wrong')
                    return



def main():
    while 1:
        event_handler = ChangeHandler()
        observer = Observer()
        observer.schedule(event_handler, folder_to_track, recursive=True)
        observer.start()

        try:
            while True:
                time.sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            observer.stop()
        observer.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, you have an infinite loop (`while file_exists:`) if either file already exists in the destination folder and does not get deleted.  Also, not a bug per se, but you can use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to build up your path string.

Comment: @PhilBrubaker I was tweaking with adding a counter and forgot to remove the ```while file_exists:``` thank you for pointing that out.

by removing that I was able to get it running and handling everything properly but now i'm at a little bit of a more complex road block.  I'd like to have subprocesses run at the same time independent of each other triggered by a function for what actually uses the data once it's found and cleaned.  I was thinking of having a new terminal window open up and run the script for using the cleaned data then closing out.  Mac doesn't have that option it seems tho.